# how to change from default esx_progressbar to ox_lib progressbar interface es_extended 1.9.4

Tags: lua, fivem

how to change from default esx_progressbar to ox_lib progressbar interface es_extended 1.9.4

es_extended/client/functions.lua

line 65 to 71

```lua
function ESX.Progressbar(message, length, Options)
    if GetResourceState("esx_progressbar") ~= "missing" then
        return exports["esx_progressbar"]:Progressbar(message, length, Options)
    end

    print("[^1ERROR^7] ^5ESX Progressbar^7 is Missing!")
end
```

I Tried With Ox lib documentation but couldnt help

Answer (score 0):

In the fxmanifest add

```
shared_scripts {
    '@es_extended/imports.lua',
    '@ox_lib/init.lua'
}
```

And i Progress.lua delete everything and add this instead

```
local function Progressbar(message, length, Options)
    local success = lib.progressBar({
        duration = length or 3000,
        label = message or "BachWorks Converted this",
        canCancel = true,
        disable = {
            car = Options.FreezePlayer,
            move = Options.FreezePlayer,
            combat = Options.FreezePlayer,
        },
        anim = {
            dict = Options.animation.dict,
            clip = Options.animation.lib,
        },
    })
    if success then
        if Options.onFinish then
            Options.onFinish()
        end
    else
        if Options.onCancel then
            Options.onCancel()
        end
    end
end

local function CancelProgressbar()
    lib.cancelProgress()
end

exports("Progressbar", Progressbar)
exports("CancelProgressbar", CancelProgressbar)

RegisterCommand("test_prog", function()
    exports["esx_progressbar"]:Progressbar("BachWorks", 5000, {
        FreezePlayer = true,
        animation = {
            type = "anim",
            dict = "anim@mp_player_intmenu@key_fob@",
            lib = "fob_click",
        },
        onFinish = function()
            print("TEST PROGRESSBAR BY BACHWORKS")
        end,
        onCancel = function()
            print("TEST PROGRESSBAR BY BACHWORKS STOP")
        end,
    })
end, false)
```